# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add

Tags: spring, maven-2, maven

after adding spring webflow, jsf dependencies, i am getting the exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;
```

any ideas how to solve this issue ?

pom file:

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version> 
        <tiles.version>2.1.3</tiles.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- a collection of internal and external dependencies -->
    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
            <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        -->


        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

            <!-- Scope controls which dependencies are available in which classpath, and which dependencies are included with an application -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- End Of Spring Dependencies -->

        <!-- Container-provided dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Provides database connection pooling services 
        (technique used for sharing server resources among requesting clients) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- End Of Hibernate Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


      <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>8.1-407.jdbc3</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- WebFlow, JSF Dependencies -->

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.springframework.webflow</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.springframework.js</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.springframework.faces</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.springframework.binding</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.15</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.jboss.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
      </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used latest version of spring 3.0.5 and version 2.2.1 of webflow and exception was gone.

Answer (score 4):

This method was added in Spring 3.x

it presents in this spring release:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues.html

but is absent in this Spring release:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues.html

It looks like you are using the 2.5.x or older version of org.springframework.beans jar.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i found that one of my dependency is downloading spring-beans 2.5.6 A but i don't know what dependency is it, any help ?

Comment: it's strange since i am downloading this dependency separately with version 3: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: i tried the command: mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework:org.springframework.beans to find what dependency is downloading the spring beans, and found out that it's: org.springframework.webflow, so i added an exclusion to it but it doesn't work

Comment: here's the exclusion: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.springframework.webflow</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>           
      </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      </dependency>

Comment: and from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.webflow/org.springframework.webflow/2.0.5.RELEASE, i can find that org.springframework.flow depends on spring version of spring-beans, so it should be 3.0.0, strange

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not big Maven expert, I don't know how to help you further on that issue, I just helped you to find root cause for it :)