# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)

Tags: spring

I am getting the below error when I try to configure a spring-hibernate application:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;

I have org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.M3.jar in the build path.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461915/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-beans-mutablepropertyvalues-add)

Why you are using 3.0.0.M3 ?

Try to upgrade your spring version to 3.0.0.RELEASE.

add method was added in

### Changes in version 3.0.0.RC3 (2009-12-01)

- added chaining-capable "add" method to MutablePropertyValues