# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues

Tags: java, spring, maven

I using:
    Maven           3.3.1,
    Java            SE 1.7,
    JavaServerFaces 2.1,
    JPA             2.0,
    Spring          4.0.9,
    Hibernate       4.1.9.Final,
and I'm getting following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;
```

My pom.xml:

```
    <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId> 
       <artifactId>org.springframework.webflow</artifactId> 
       <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version> 
       <exclusions> 
        <exclusion> 
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> 
       </exclusions> 
   </dependency> 
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> 
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version> 
  </dependency> 
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My Maven Dependencies:

- spring 2.5.6.jar
- org.springframework.webflow 2.0.5.RELEASE
- org.springframework.binding 2.0.5.RELEASE
- org.springframework.js 2.0.5.RELEASE
- spring-aspects 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-beans 4.0.9RELEASE
- spring-context-support 4.0.9.REALEASE
- spring-instrument 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-jdbc 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-jms 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-orm 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-oxm 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-messaging 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-web 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-test 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-webmvc 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-expression 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-webmvc-portlet 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-websocket 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-data-jpa 1.8.0.RELEASE
- spring-data-commons 1.10.0.RELEASE
- spring-context 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-aop 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-tx 4.0.9.RELEASE
- spring-core 4.0.9.RELEASE

I read [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461915/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-beans-mutablepropertyvalues-add) but I could not find an answer.
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here:

[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461915/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-beans-mutablepropertyvalues-add)

The method was added in Spring 3.x

Comment: I had 2 spring 2.5.6 jars in my library. I removed one and now it is running. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use version `2.4.1.RELEASE` of `spring-webflow`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Version 2.0.5.RELEASE works with spring framework version 2.x

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: @Alexandra Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project?