# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist when it does exist

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have placed my dispatcher-servlet.xml inside the WEB-INF folder which is placed inside webapp folder.
Still it is throwing error as:class path resource [WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist.

I searched for the error and it was suggested to place the WEB-INF directly under src/main/resources.
I placed it inside the resources folder but it is failing at Context Initialisation with the following error:

> Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;

Unable to track the error,where it is going wrong?

Below is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.travel.test"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename"
            value="classpath:com/travel/test/i18n" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US" />
        <property name="cookieName" value="AppLocaleCookie"></property>
        <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
      <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
      <property name="locations">
          <list>
            <value>classpath:com/travel/test/${Environment:e0}-env.properties</value>
          </list>
      </property>
     </bean>    

    <mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/static/**"/>
  <!--  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />-->

      <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" p:definitions="/WEB-INF/conf/tiles-defs.xml" /> 

</beans>
```

Any suggestions where it is going wrong?

Added pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aexp.travel.docdelivery.tcapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>travel</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>travel</name>


    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <slf.version>1.6.1</slf.version>
        <tiles.version>2.2.2</tiles.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8
        </project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId> 
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId> 
            <version>3.2.1</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
           </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why your title mentioned *java.io.FileNotFoundException* and in the text you talk about * java.lang.NoSuchMethodError* ?

Comment: Initailly i faced  java.io.FileNotFoundException  but while resolving and again deploying the war file i am facing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.So,not sure If while replacig the dispatcher-servlet.xml is causing the error

Comment: what is the versions of spring jars? if there is pom, please post relevant part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461915/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-beans-mutablepropertyvalues-add)

Comment: The `WEB-INF` isn't part (nor should be part) of the classpath. Your move kind of made it work, but destroyed the correct webapp archive. So you are loading your file in the wrong way. Moving it "solved" the issue but showed another issue, which probably is related to mixing modules from different versions of spring. But first move your `WEB-INF` back to `src/main/webapp` and load your file from the correct location.

Comment: @M.Denium I have already moved my dispatcher-servlet.xml to original src/main/webapp location

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam No I already tried from past two days...No Luck

Comment: @lakshman...Added pom.xml ...please suggest

Comment: Why is it trying to load even from the classpath? This means you have overriden some configuration to do something other then the default. Add your `web.xml`.