# FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist when it does exist

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have placed my dispatcher-servlet.xml inside the WEB-INF folder which is placed inside webapp folder. Still it is throwing error as:class path resource [WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist.

Exception:Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;

Unable to track the error,where it is going wrong?

Below is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.travel.test"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename"
            value="classpath:com/travel/test/i18n" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US" />
        <property name="cookieName" value="AppLocaleCookie"></property>
        <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
      <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
      <property name="locations">
          <list>
            <value>classpath:com/travel/test/${Environment:e0}-env.properties</value>
          </list>
      </property>
     </bean>    

    <mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/static/**"/>
  <!--  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />-->

      <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" p:definitions="/WEB-INF/conf/tiles-defs.xml" /> 

</beans>
```

And below is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aexp.travel.docdelivery.tcapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>travel</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>travel</name>


    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <slf.version>1.6.1</slf.version>
        <tiles.version>2.2.2</tiles.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8
        </project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId> 
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId> 
            <version>3.2.1</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
           </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any suggestion where it is wrong?

Comment: The message is absolutely right. The classpath of a webapp is WEB-INF/classes + all the jars under WEB-INF/lib. So WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml can't be found using the classpath.

Comment: so,where it should be placed..because if I deploy the project as ear it is woring fine but incase of war it is failig

Comment: I have no idea of what is causing spring to try to load this file from the classpath. You probably misconfigured something in web.xml. Find where, in all your files, you reference the path WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml.

Comment: i have something configured as below in web.xml:<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
  classpath:/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
  </param-value>
 </context-param>

Comment: There you go. Remove the `classpath:` prefix.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet,I was able to resolve this but ran into other issue of dispatcher-servlet... Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;

Comment: That shows that you're using incompatible versions of Spring libraries Use Maven utilities to debug your dependencies. Why are you starting (I guess) a new project with Java 6 and Spring 3.1? Those are completely obsolete versions.

Comment: I am using Spring 3.1 with java 1.8

Comment: And, as I said, Spring 3.1 is completely obsolete. It hasn't even been tested on Java 8 bacause it's so old. And your pom is configured for Java 6.

Comment: i changed my pom configuration to 1.8 but still the same issue.Upgrading Spring version is not  worthy as it is a legacy project and upgrading spring version will result in many other changes

Comment: If it's a legacy project, then I surely hope it was running fine before you made a change that caused this error to happen. So check what change you just made to cause this error to happen.

Comment: it was previously deployed as an ear project and now i need to make it as an war deployed application+java version upgrade

Comment: Please don't ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59244701/java-io-filenotfoundexception-class-path-resource-web-inf-dispatcher-servlet-x) again. Instead edit your original question.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Your project is using too old dependencies

> Change like this to use Java 8 in your pom.xm

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> And use this [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7469351/7765316) of spring for your legacy project

```
<spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

---

> Please make sure you have this kind of configuration in your web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: yeah,i do have this configuration in xml.However i was able to resolve this now and facing issue with Method not found in dispatcher-servlet as:Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues

Comment: What is your spring version?

Comment: Spring 3.1.0 RELEASE and java 1.8

Comment: Change <source>1.6</source><target>1.6</target> to <source>1.8</source> <target>1.8</target> and use latest spring version to resolve this issue

Comment: I updated the answer, please try it and let me know

Comment: ,Upgrading spring version is not affordable to me since I am working on some legacy project and increasing the verion is giving many other errors

Comment: However I have updated the Java vesion as suggested by you,but it is not working

Comment: that's why i suggested version 3.0.5, please have a look again